# Why is NLog not archiving anymore

Tags: c#, nlog

I had this configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="bot.log" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="10" enableArchiveFileCompression="true"/>
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

It worked previously creating bot.1.zip, bot.2.zip etc... but now it always appends to existing file though I haven't changed anything.

I updated NLog just now and the issue persists.

Comment: Maybe check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting?

Comment: even if you delete all previous archives?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove the bindingRedirect for System.IO.Compression in app.config and now it works again.

Thanks [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201303/julian) for [troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting)